# Gate driver selection for digitally controlled via PFM, LLC resonant half bridge charger

Tags: control-system, charger, gate-driving, component-selection, llc-converter

I am designing a LLC half bridge charger. I am going to use a microcontroller to control the switching frequency, with feedback from the output to smoothly control the switching requency.

I don't understand how can I control the MOSFET's switching cycle with control input of gate drivers. In the market there is a resonant driver but I don't understand how to control it digitally with, for example, an FAN7621.

Comment: That's the neat part, you don't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't understand how can I control the MOSFET's switching cycle with control input of gate drivers. In the market there is a resonant driver but I don't understand how to control it digitally with, for example, an FAN7621.

FAN7621 is not what you are looking for. You can't control it digitally as it's an analog controller which has everything internally.

What you need is a combined high- and low-side driver, not a controller. There are many gate drive ICs in the market. IR2112 is one of them, though I don't recommend it.

- These ICs generally use [bootstrapping](https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/eu/semiconductor/knowledge/faq/linear_high-voltage-ipds/high-voltage06.html) to drive the high-side switch, so make sure the IC's bridge node (generally named as VS node) voltage rating is higher than your maximum DC input voltage. For example, IR2112's VS node rating is 600V, and if your max DC input voltage is 450V then it's suitable.
- For LLC HB converter the dead time is important, especially for ZVS (zero voltage switching), overall efficiency and general operation. So make sure the IC you select does **NOT** generate a fixed dead time or if it does it should match your needs. Ideally, it should be under your control for maximum performance.
- You may also want a high peak drive current capability (generally around 1 A) for simplicity. Although the turn on time is not important in an LLC so a relatively high gate stopper resistor (which means lower peak gate drive current) generally works, the turn off time is important. So if you don't want external transistors (i.e. totem pole or push-pull) it's better to choose an IC with high peak current capability.

---

Another options are:

1. Drive the low-side switch directly and the high-side with a dedicated high-side driver.
2. Use gate drive transformers.